# How to get a User's Calendar Default IANA Time Zone from Google Calendar API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I would like to get the default IANA time zone of a user's calendar (which is not necessarily the same timezone that the person as in--or else [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091399/4206520) would work fine).

I believe the way to do this may be with [Settings `timezone`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/settings) to get the time, but the documentation does not seem to cover javascript for this specifically.

**This is my attempt, which is inspired by a mix of google's docs [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) and [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/):**

```
var timeZoneCalendar = window.gapi.client.calendar.get({
  resourceName: '/users/me/settings/timeZoneId'
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.result);
}, function(reason) {
  console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
});
```

This unfortunately only gives me the error of `window.gapi.client.calendar.get is not a function`.

I already use the `window.gapi.client.calendar.events.insert`, `window.gapi.client.calendar.events.update`, and `window.gapi.client.calendar.events.list` in my project so it shouldn't be the `window.gapi.client.calendar` that is the issue.

Does anyone have any guesses on how to get this?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the successful calls you were using always included `events` object. I think you should use [`events.get`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) as well like what you did with `events.list`., `events.insert` and `events.update`.

```
window.gapi.client.calendar.get
```

change to:

```
window.gapi.client.calendar.events.get
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  The events object allows me to access information for the events themselves, but since I am trying to access the Settings of the calendar rather than any particular event, I also tried `window.gapi.client.calendar.settings.get`, but to no avail.

Comment: What error response do you get when using window.gapi.client.calendar.settings.get?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined`